# How do I associated a lead created through Apex to an existing Pardot visitor?

Tags: apex, pardot

Suppose I have an existing Pardot visitor_id I get through cookies and then after a user submits a web form to me I invoke a Salesforce web service that creates a lead for me. How do I associate the lead to an existing Pardot visitor?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the definitive answer to your question but I think I can point you in the right direction.

### Assumptions

1. You've configured a CRM connector between Pardot and Salesforce
2. You have access to the Pardot API

### Here's your sequence of events

An anonymous visitor has browsed your site and a Pardot cookie was created by the Pardot tracking code, and you gain access to the visitor_id value from that cookie.

Somehow you've gained information from this person without telling Pardot and you've created a Lead record that represents them.

Pardot and Salesforce will synchronize (*here's my assumption that you configured a connector*) and a new Prospect will be created in Pardot that matches the Lead record in Salesforce.

**At this moment the newly-created Prospect is not associated with the Visitor (visitor_id) that YOU know is the same human being.**

Here's where the API comes in. You can use the API to *tell* Pardot that a specific visitor_id should match a specific Prospect.

```
/api/visitor/version/4/do/assign/id/<visitor_id>?prospect_id=<prospect_id>&api_key=<api_key>&user_key=<user_key>
```

Scroll to the bottom of this API documentation to see more: 
[Visitors API Documentation](http://developer.pardot.com/kb/api-version-4/visitors/)

You can get the prospect_id from the API by searching for your new Prospect.